# CGI-call to .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, cgi, callback, payment-gateway

I have the following scenario. I have created an ASP.NET web application (framework 3.5) for my company, which allows users to purchase goods or services. Then, the user clicks on "Proceed to Payment", which calls an external payment site. The user then enters the card details through this site.

The payment site are performing a CGI-call to an .aspx page (say Successful.aspx) in case of successful transaction by the user. So, I created this .aspx page and placed it in the root of my website, together with its aspx.vb file (which will perform the processing on successful transaction like setting the Paid, PaidDate fields etc). What is occurring is that the transaction is successful, and the logs from the payment site company show that the Successful.aspx is being found and called...however, none of the processing is being performed by the Successful.aspx.vb (i.e. the fields are not being set at all).

Is there something about CGI calls that I am missing?

Comment: Can you see the hit to Sucessful.aspx in your IIS logs?  Does Sucessful.aspx work fine if you load it in a browser?

Comment: The Successful.aspx page is being found by the payment site. It is a normal and minimal.aspx page. I was suspecting that maybe with a CGI callback the codebehind does not get called?

Comment: The CGI hitting the aspx is the same as a browser hitting it.

Comment: Hi Russau, thanks for your comments. So, when the Successful.aspx page gets hit, Session_Start gets called in Global.asax.vb too? Cause for this application, you have to be logged on to go to specific pages, but in Session_Start I am making an exception so that in case of any page, there will be a redirect to "Login.aspx", but in the case of the URL containing "Successful.aspx", it will redirect to Request.Rawurl.tostring. Will the URL be the same as in a browser for this CGI call and can I redirect as I am attempting? Thanks.

Comment: Session_Start will probably fire with every hit - as the CGI client wouldn't be storing the cookies between successive hits.  Check in your IIS logs to see if you are getting a 200 status code (success) or 302 (redirect).  It's also possible the client won't obey the redirect, best to avoid that if you can.

Comment: OK, solved! In the Session_Start, I removed the Response.Redirect if the page was "Successful.aspx" (There is no point redirecting as it would naturally continue execution there if it does not go to "Login.aspx") and it works. The payment company gave me the logs and it indicated "302 found" and I figured it had to do with the redirect.
Thanks a lot.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the final answer was:

- Session_Start fires with every hit from the 3rd party, as session cookies don't get stored/passed by the client.
- Session_Start contained redirect code.  The 3rd party was getting the status 302, and not obeying the redirect AND logging this as a success.
- The fix - remove the redirect from Session_Start, and the 3rd party never gets sent a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Response.Expires = -1 in your Successful.aspx. It might have been cached.

Secondly, what does the user have to once he's sent to successful.aspx after payments ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it seems the solution was something different. I was incorrectly redirecting and this causing problems together with the CGI call.
Thanks.